# Android databinding cannot resolve symbol (gradle 3.0.1)

Tags: android, android-databinding

I think I might be missing something obvious, the binding has no access to my textview id? eg.

> binding.myText.setText("text here"); > cannot resolve symbol 'myText'

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.myText.setText("test");
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

*edit*

---

**app/build.gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.francoismarais.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**build.gradle (root)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you try a clean/rebuild?

Comment: i did, let me try invalidate cache and restart. i also added my gradle files, maby something is missing there :|

Comment: alright, I did an invalidate caches and restart, that seemed to have kicked it into a working state now :) sorry for the obvious question

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
```

Change `gradle:3.0.1` to `gradle:3.0.0`

Comment: invalidate cache and restart seemed to have worked :)

Comment: - it's not a solution.